# How to set line color with a given rgb value?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a `seaborn.lineplot()`, and a list of rgb values such as `[26,201,55]`.

I don't know which parameter I can set in `sns.lineplot` to change the color as I wish.
Here is my wrong code:

```
sns.lineplot(x='Episode',y='Mean Reward',sizes=(.25,.25),hue='Agent', data=df[0], palette=[r_rl/255,g_rl/255,b_rl/255]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a parameter `palette` for defining colors, `palette` is just a list of colors defined as `tuples` with 3 values between 0 and 1.

If you have one color, you can use:

```
palette=[(r_rl/255, g_rl/255, b_rl/255)]
```

But for multiple colors:

```
rgb = [(66, 135, 245), (255, 25, 0)]                # first blue, second red
colors = [tuple(t / 255 for t in x) for x in rgb]
```

And then use:

```
sns.lineplot(
    x="Episode",
    y="Mean Reward",
    sizes=(0.25, 0.25),
    hue="Agent",
    data=df[0],
    palette=colors,
)
```

Random example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rgb = [(66, 135, 245), (255, 25, 0)]
colors = [tuple(t / 255 for t in x) for x in rgb]

sns.set()
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
ax = sns.lineplot(
    x="timepoint",
    y="signal",
    hue="event",
    data=fmri,
    palette=colors,
)
```

Result:

[image]